# Which algorithm (Vincenty or Haversine) is used to calculate distance in GeoTools?

Tags: geotools

I want to use GeoTools library to calculate geographic distance by using GeodeticCalculator (as mentioned in here http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/calculator.html ).

Does this library use Vincenty formula, Haversine, or something else?

Comment: JTS is the underlying library for non-geographic geometries, if you asked about that it would be "neither, it's euclidean". I have removed JTS from your question is it was misleading to include.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GeoTools uses Karney's [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/), if you check [the code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/referencing/src/main/java/org/geotools/referencing/GeodeticCalculator.java#L648) you'll see it uses the [Geodesic.Direct method](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/java/net/sf/geographiclib/Geodesic.html#Direct-double-double-double-boolean-double-int-).